# Как реализовать таблицу логин отдельно, профиль отдельно?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Подскажите как id users_profile  нужно присваивать id из таблицы users
При создании строки в users.

> (таблица user только для логина активации почты и тд) 20 полей

И users_profile  30 полей

И правильно ли это id будет схоже с id из user или сделать его уникальным и добавить поле users_id?

Можно пример или статью.

Comment: А зачем профиль отдельно ? между ними вообще какая связь ожидается один к одному что ли ?

Comment: связь да, я  хочу чтобы строка в user_profile автоматически создавалась при добавление строки user и id user_profile  заносился в поле user

Comment: Напишите триггер на таблицу user, который собственно строку в профайле будет создавать. хотя особого смысла делать вторую таблицу я не вижу. Но конечно надо смотреть что за поля, может для части из них уже пора вводить EAV, особенно если они часто добавляются новые

Comment: @Mike Я просто не знаком с базами, то есть 50 столбцов нормально? Про EAV знаю это типо характеристики? Пока в разработке думаю над структурой

Comment: ну не обязательно характеристики. Что там у вас например в профиле ? телефоны, страницы с соцсетях, email ? Все перечисленное - это контакты и они просто напрашиваются на вынесение в отдельную таблицу, особенно с учетом что практически любого из видов контактов может быть много. Но 50 полей у одной сущности в принципе нормально. Главное что бы каждое из полей означало совершенно уникальный атрибут. в смысле что бы не было "телефон 1", "телефон 2"

Comment: @Mike Да такая заметочка забыл пользователи все равно не смогут просматривать и изменять поля из user и хотелось бы после удаления юзера оставлять профиль. Про контакты я понял типо вместо массива использовать EAV  для нескольких телефонов у пользователя? Если да то нет у меня все 30 уникальны и 10 может где то как раз с EAV, там телефон только 1 указать можно. Вопрос еще присваивать в первичный id users_profile от id users  это норм?

Comment: Думаю свой id профилю не нужен. он бы понадобился если бы вы захотели двум пользователям один профиль дать, что вряд ли. Так что первичным делать прямо тот id, что у пользователя. Хотя жизнь профиля после удаления пользователя это интересно. Само по себе вроде собственного id все равно не требует, но как бы эта жизнь не потащила за собой еще что нибудь ...